# How to access packages?

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote a program `HelloWorld.java` 
and stored in a folder(package) named `test` that test includes `hello` folder by itself.
and all in my workspace.

I mean this way: `d:\workspace\test\hello\HellWorld.java`
And I entered the `d:\workspace` in my path environment, my code:

```
package test.hello;
public class HelloWorld
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("HelloAll");
    }
 }
```

When I go to the hello directory at CMD and compile `HelloWorld.java` everything is fine and done.
but as I use java `HelloWorld` (in `d:\workspace\test\hello`) I get exception in thread main error.

Can you help me with this just simple question?

Comment: "i get exeption in thread main error" - What is the exact error message? It contains important information about what is wrong.

Comment: Exepction in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld<wrong name test\hello\HelloWorld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in cmd windows go d:\workspace and issue the following cmd

> d:>workspace>java test.hello.HelloWorld

Comment: i know this..but i want call HelloWorld without declare specific directory!
how can i do this?
is everything true?!
i want that as i writed java HelloWorld, it runes.

Comment: @user2857832 This is not possible, when you want to run a class which has a main method then you have to specify its fully qualified name i.e. including package. Unless you define the class in the default package, in that case the fully qualified name is the class name itself, but this is discouraged.

Comment: u mean if i write a class that includes no main method,and compile,then i can run it without specific directory?

Comment: @The.Only.One To be able run a class it needs to have an entry point. The entry point in a java application is the method `public static void main(String[] args) {}`, which means for a java class: No main -> no entry -> no execution/running!

Answer (score 2):

You must use the fully qualified name of your class to run it.

Stand in  `d:\workspace\`

Run:

```
 java test.hello.HelloWorld
```

Comment: i know this..but i want call HelloWorld without declare specific directory! how can i do this? is everything true?! i want that as i writed java HelloWorld, it runes

Comment: @user2857832 Then you need to remove the `package test.hello;` in HelloWorld.java. You can't do that when HelloWorld is part of a specific package.

Answer (score 1):

**cd** to d:\workspace

Compile using-

> javac -d . HelloWorld.java

The above will create package structure.

Run using-

> java test.hello.HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `java` command from your source directory i.e. `d:\workspace` as mentioned here:

```
java test.hello.HelloWorld
```

The syntax is simple, just go to your source code directory and not the package directory. Use the classname along with full package name.

Comment: i know this..but i want call HelloWorld without declare specific directory! how can i do this? is everything true?! i want that as i writed java HelloWorld, it runes

Comment: @The.Only.One You cannot run a java class without the package name except if it is present in default pacakge. The reason is simple, you may have multiple classes with the same name but in different packages.